# Bidirectional Binding ImageView to byte[]

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Iam trying to display a image in Imageview which is read from byteArray

```
  Image image= new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(item.getImageBytes()));
  imageview.setImage(image);
```

this is working fine 
but i want to bind image to bytearray something like

```
imageview.imageProperty().bind(/*No getting anything what to write here*/);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot bind an image to a bytearray. You are already converting the ByteArray to an image; why not bind to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have this:

```
public class Foo {
    private final ObjectProperty<byte[]> imageBytes = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

You can use this:

```
imageview.imageProperty().bind(
        Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(item.getImageBytes()))
            , item.imageBytesProperty()));
```

Comment: i'm not to able to find Bindings.createObjectProperty in  javafx.beans.binding; could you tell me the package name to be imported .

Comment: @kamaltej Typo. Edited.